# Proof of correctness of divide and conquer clique algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, correctness-proof, divide-and-conquer

I have the following divide and conquer algorithm that finds a clique in an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$:

```
CLIQUE(G):

1) Number the vertices V as 1,2,3...,n where n=|V|

2) If n = 1, return V

3) Divide V in v1 = {1,2,...,[n/2]} and v2 = {[n/2]+1,...,n}

4) Being G1 the subgraph induced by V1 and G2 the subgraph induced by V2,
   find C1 = CLIQUE(G1) and C2 = CLIQUE(G2)

5) Combine the results in the following way:
   5.1. Initialize C1+ as C1 and c2+ as C2
   5.2. For every vertex v ∈ C2, if v is connected to all vertices in c1+
        then add v to c1+
   5.3. For every vertex v ∈ C1, if v is connected to all vertices in c2+
        then add v to c2+
   5.4. Return the bigger between c1+ and c2+
```

The algorithm is definitive and cannot be changed, and I need to prove that it always returns a subgraph of G that is a clique (don't know how to do it) and find its time complexity, on the time complexity, analyzing the algorithm I have arrived to the following recurrence: $T(n) = n + n·m+2T(n/2)$, which following the master theorem leads to an $O(n·m)$ complexity, but i found that cloque algorithms are exponential, so i must have done something wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: For proving recursive algorithms correct, induction is usually a good start.

Comment: What are you actually asking for? Your title talks about proving correctness but the question body is about running time. What did you try? Where did you get stuck? And, honestly, this looks a lot like you're trying to get us to do your homework. It's hard to imagine why else you'd be so wedded to this particular algorithm without even knowing if it's correct or efficient.

Comment: Your algorithm will always return *a* clique, but that's trivial (since returning any single vertex would also satisfy that requirement).  It certainly won't return a maximum-sized (or even maximal) clique.

Comment: "The algorithm is definitive and cannot be changed" -- why?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Finally I found a way to prove that the result will always return a clique using induction, but since there has been a lot since I proved anythiong by induction I dindn't have any clue on what to do. I use this algorithm because we where asked to find an algorithm to find cliques, then present it and once the teacher said that the algorithm was ok, we were asked to prove its correctness and efficiency. I'm sorry if it seemed that I wanted you to do my homework, I was only expecting a clue and to know if my complexity is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wanted your algorithm to return a maximum clique, here's a small counterexample:

Let $G$ be the triangle $abc$, plus the two isolated points $d$ and $e$.  Suppose that $V$ is divided so that $v_1 = \{a, d\}$ and $v_2 = \{b, c, e\}$.  Then CLIQUE($G_1$) will return either $a$ or $d$; suppose it returns $d$.  CLIQUE($G_2$) will return (at best; i.e., if it were in fact implemented correctly) the edge $bc$.  But neither $b$ nor $c$ is adjacent to *every* vertex in $c_1$ (in fact neither is adjacent to *any* vertex in $c_1$, since $c_1 = \{d\}$ and $d$ is an isolated point), and likewise $d$ is not adjacent to *every* (in fact *any*) vertex in $c_2$ (since $d$ remains an isolated point), thus step 5 fails to find a bigger clique, despite the fact that $abc$ is a clique of size 3.

This counterexample also shows that the algorithm can fail to find a maxim*al* clique, which is a much weaker requirement.

Comment: But if CLIQUE(G1) returns C1 = a and CLIQUE(G2) returns C2 = b-c, b and c are connected to a (all the vertices of C1), so the algorithm would return the triangle abc, isn't that right?

Comment: @flapedriza: Correct, I'll fix my counterexample now.

Comment: @flapedriza: BTW, another direction in which your algorithm fails is that there may exist a maximum clique in $G$ that is completely *disjoint from* all maximum cliques induced by each of $V_1$ and $V_2$ -- e.g. it may well be that $V_1$ and $V_2$ each induce triangles $abc$ and $def$, respectively, but that a larger clique $efgh$ exists having $\{e, f\} \in V_1$ and $\{g, h\} \in V_2$.  (And the fact that I had to write "*all* maximum cliques" in the previous sentence hints at a third direction: What if there are multiple maximum cliques in at least one of the 2 subgraphs?)